# Multiple, alternative USB extensions

Tags: usb

I have a controller box as 'client' normally connected directly with a USB cable to the host computer. What I would like to have is basically an intermediate fixed installed extension 'network' that would allow me to plug in the PC at different points around the room to access the controller, essentially just a few fixed USB extension cables connected to one another. It currently looks like this:

```
 Controller_____
                |
                |_______ Socket A
                |_______ Socket B                  .....PC
                |_______ Socket C________D
```

so a bit of a star topology with one arm as a daisy chain. Just to emphasize, this is not meant to function as a real network, there is ever only one controller, and there is ever only one PC, plugged in alternatively to A, B, C, or D.

Now here is the problem: Each socket works on its own, but not if they are all electrically connected (at '|'). So, for example controller to PC at A works fine, as long as I disconnect the other sockets (B, C). Bizarrely, I can use the daisy chain at C or D with out Problem (as long as I have disconnected A and B), but if I then try to extend for example the chain from C to B, again none of C, D, or B work (i.e. 'host does not recognize USB device'). In fact, it is enough to add a bit of open wire at D to get this effect.
What is going on? Any clues? Is length an issue? Does this need terminators (resistor?) at each unused end (how)?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have connected the sockets in parallel by soldering the wires together? Or do you have a switch to select the upstream port?

Comment: They are effectively in parallel through a connector block - no switches involved

Comment: Is the device USB2 or USB1 (high or full speed)?

Comment: It all runs under USB 2.0 from the PC side, I do not really know what the Control Box has implemented, the manufacturer does not say, but I suspect it is 2.0 as well (however, data transfer rate is not really important, as there are only occasional commands and feedback messages transmitted, so it may be still 1.1., but as it is a current device I doubt it)

Comment: Why not a series of regular extension cords, which you disconnect when you connect the PC? You still need to respect the quite short maximum USB cable length, just a few metres...

Comment: Yes, I understand the total length restrictions, that should not be the problem. And yes I could mess around with plugging unplugging various extension cords, but that's exactly what I try to avoid. It just seems that having a few extra bits of copper connected messes up the Impedance/Data Transmission of all the line(s).

Comment: This won't work. USB is purely a point to point connection and adding on all these lengths of cable will upset the impedance enough to make it fail. Even if you only want a low level of throughput, the USB2 bus protocol itself still runs at 480 Mbps. Splitting the data pair out into a connector block may be enough to make it fail on its own.